# How can I get the class name for a table in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Finding the table name for a class in DBIx::Class is straightforward, like this

```
my $s = DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->connect('dbi:SQLite:foo.db');
$s->class($class_name)->table;
```

but how can I do the opposite, and get the class name from the name of the table in the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`$schema->sources`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#sources) to get a list of all source names in a schema. Then you can grep for the one matching your table:

```
my ($class_name) = grep { $s->class($_)->table eq $table } $s->sources;
```

Comment: Thanks - I was doing this, though, and I was looking for amore straight, elegant way.